# Dropbox Sync within Mega Sync

Tags: synchronization, dropbox, megasync

(I'm not sure this is the right forum to ask this, but will try).

I have two computers: one at home, and one at the office. I am syncing a `/Documents` folder between these, using MegaSync desktop client. This folder includes a `/Personal` and a `/Work` subfolder. For example, the structure is like this:

[image]

I want to sync the `/Work` subfolder with another colleague, who uses Dropbox. Thus, I have to use Dropbox too. I'm not entirely sure how exactly the syncing happens between two computers and a server, and I am worried that having a sync inside another sync will introduce a lot of "conflict copies", of files updated in different computers by my colleague or myself. I am thinking an alternative would be to move the `/Work` subfolder outside the `/Documents` folder, having simply two separate syncs.

What is the right method to store the data in order to avoid/minimize conflicts?